# Divide regex rules in two parts for jquery validate

Tags: regex, validation

I am not good with regex need your help, I am working on jQuery Validate here is working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/3ssygt21/13/

I have two regex used in it

```
^(\+44)[0-9]+$
```

and

```
^(?=(?:.{14})$)
```

How to modify these two so that

1st one only check for prefix +44 (I mean once entered +44 it should return true)

2nd one only check for number followed by + symbol with length 14.

Comment: 1) `/^\+44/` and 2) `/^\+.{14}$/`?

Comment: I think you should add another filter to check if preceding characters are all numbers as well.